# C# Linq return SortedList

Tags: c#, linq, sortedlist

How can I get Linq in C# to return a [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) given an `IEnumerable`? If I can't, is it possible to cast or transform the `IEnumerable` to a `SortedList`?

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way would probably be to create a dictionary using `ToDictionary`, and then call the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>(dictionary)` constructor. Alternatively, add your own extension method:

```
public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TSource, TKey, TValue>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
     Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
{
    // Argument checks elided
    SortedList<TKey, TValue> ret = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        // Will throw if the key already exists
        ret.Add(keySelector(item), valueSelector(item));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This will allow you to create `SortedList`s with anonymous types as the values:

```
var list = people.ToSortedList(p => p.Name,
                               p => new { p.Name, p.Age });
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use the `IDictionary` constructor so use the `ToDictionary` extension method on your linq query and then use new `SortedList(dictionary);`

e.g.

```
 var list=new SortedList(query.ToDictionary(q=>q.KeyField,q=>q));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works just fine

```
List<MyEntity> list = DataSource.GetList<MyEntity>(); // whatever data you need to get

SortedList<string, string> retList = new SortedList<string, string> ();

list.ForEach ( item => retList.Add ( item.IdField, item.Description ) );
```